# Simple function counting values from a list within certain range

Tags: r

I want to create a function that takes 3 arguments: a list of values and two cutoff values (a high and a low). Then I want it to how many of the values in the list are within the range of the two cutoff values.

So far I have tried:

```
count <- function(y, x1, x2){
  tmp1 <- length(y)
  tmp2 <- length(y>x1)
  tmp3 <- length(tmp2<=x2)
  return(tmp3)
}
```

and

```
count <- function(y, x1, x2){
  results <- list()
  for (i in y) {
    if(y > x1 & y <= x2) {
      results <- results+1
    }
  }
  return(results)
}
```

none of them work. Can some help me correct my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplify it down. Take the sum of a vectorized logical operation

```
f <- function(x, y, z) sum(x > y & x < z)
f(1:10, 3, 7)
# [1] 3
```

But the `data.table` authors are one step ahead of you. They've written a function `between()`. I believe there is also one in the `dplyr` package as well.

```
library(data.table)
between
# function (x, lower, upper, incbounds = TRUE) 
# {
#     if (incbounds) 
#         x >= lower & x <= upper
#     else x > lower & x < upper
# }
# <bytecode: 0x44fc790>
# <environment: namespace:data.table>
```

So for the same result as above you can simply do

```
sum(between(1:10, 3, 7, FALSE))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: This is so simple I am actually embarrassed. I have made it way more complex than I had to. Thank you so much!

Comment: @rawr - I haven't seen one in base, have you?  It does seem warranted but it's also quite simple to create

Comment: @Alex A: Richard answer is now accepted. Thank you for the reminder :)